# Spam in email form using .aspx language C# - how to add CAPTCHA

Tags: asp.net, captcha, spam

---- Final Solution ----

Since I am not familiar with asp - I decided to go with a jquery captcha ( thanks for all your help )

*Edit New*

I am using the reCaptcha with ASP.NET doc's found here:
https://developers.google.com/recaptcha/docs/aspnet

Okay I added the code the the page see screen shot here.
http://qualityplanners.com/1.png

I am now getting this error.
http://www.qualityplanners.com/freequotecs.aspx

The first step of the docs asks me to:
Download and Add Recaptcha.dll to the root.. how do I link it without visual studio?

Let me know
-O

*Old Below*

I need help with a client with aspx - I am only familiar with PHP.

He keeps getting spam with this old form the past web guy coded.
http://www.qualityplanners.com/freequotecs.aspx

I am looking into ways to add reCAPTCHA or an easy method to stop spam... even just adding a simple validation for whats 5+6 or something.

I tried looking into the documentation for reCAPTCHA or some other free online CAPTCHA scripts but keep getting error - I am probably installing it wrong.

Whats the correct way to do this?

This is the fiddle of the linked code.
http://dotnetfiddle.net/ROzRgl

Thanks in advance.
-O

Comment: We're not able to debug your code. Explain what you changed and show the relevant code and the actual error you're getting.

Comment: Since I was getting the error I delete the code - and the form is the way it originally was. I tried added a few things I found online and error after error

Comment: But _"How to add reCAPTCHA to an ASP.NET site?"_ is not a valid SO question (it's not specific and narrow enough). Just search the web, [find the docs](https://developers.google.com/recaptcha/docs/aspnet), try what is explained there and update your question with an actual error.

Comment: Okay, before I go and grab something online do you suggest something you may be familiar with so It will make trouble shooting easier?

Comment: The "[find the docs](https://developers.google.com/recaptcha/docs/aspnet)" part is a link. What is explained there should just work. :)

Comment: Okay CodeCaster- Step 2 I added the code to the top of the page and I get this error. see link [Screen shot](http://qualityplanners.com/1.png) - to view error is this [link](http://www.qualityplanners.com/freequotecs.aspx)

Comment: Did you actually add a reference to the assembly in visual studio and republish the site, or did you just add the directive at the top of the page?

Comment: https://code.google.com/p/recaptcha/downloads/list?q=label:aspnetlib-Latest

Comment: I just added it to the root directory, I have not added it to the page... with visual studio - I have no idea what visual studio is.. can't I just add html code to the file itself without using an application?

Answer (score 0):

I think you may have skipped step 1.

> Add a reference on your website to library/bin/Release/Recaptcha.dll:
>   On the Visual Studio Website menu, choose Add Reference and then click
>   the .NET tab in the dialog box. Select the Recaptcha.dll component
>   from the list of .NET components and then click OK. If you don't see
>   the component, click the Browse tab and look for the assembly file on
>   your hard drive.

Comment: is there a workaround because I don't have visual studio - can't I just add the hard code to the file itself?

Comment: You really need to give your client to somebody who is capable of supporting them.

Comment: Agreed - I am just doing this as a favor because hes constantly getting spam.. any alternative options? - maybe to add an extra field asking whats 2 + 2 to validate the form?

Comment: Anything else you implement will have to be purely client side.  Which means that it can easily be bypassed.  But you can implement pure javascript captcha